# Changing Snowflake Schema in Javascript

Tags: javascript

The only way I know how to get a list of columns in Snowflake Primary and Unique keys is using the `SHOW PRIMARY KEYS` and `SHOW UNIQUE KEYS` commands.  The `INFORMATION SCHEMA` views do not yet provide that detail.  The SHOW commands only operate on the current schema. I would like to use a Javascript procedure to loop through different known schemas and grab the results of the SHOW PRIMARY KEYS (and `SHOW UNIQUE KEYS`).

I can do this for the current schema, but cannot change schemas in Javascript.  Is there a way to either:
   - Change schemas in jscript, or
   - Has Snowflake improved their `INFORMATION SCHEMA` views to expose `PK` and `UK` columns like available in the SHOW commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer though it was not listed in any documentation I could find.  The SHOW command allows you to specify which schema you are inquiring on.

SHOW PRIMARY KEYS IN SCHEMA "database"."schema";